# Retrieving Logged In User Data in Android from backendless

Tags: android, backendless

i want to get the logged in user data (at least 1 attribute) from backendless's database into my android application.
I've the register/login activities, and a test activity where i want to retrieve the data.
In order to do that, i should get the logged in user identity ( is that the objectId ? ) and use query upon that objectId ?

Here's my progress so far :

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second);


        Backendless.setUrl(Defaults.SERVER_URL);
        Backendless.initApp(this, Defaults.APPLICATION_ID, Defaults.SECRET_KEY, Defaults.VERSION);

        String currentUserId = Backendless.UserService.loggedInUser();


        if (currentUserId != null)
            t1.setText("DATA");
        else
            t1.setText("NO DATA");

    }
```

and after logging in , the text is set to DATA, if i do t1.setText(currentUserId) it doesn't show anything, and i'm doing that to see if i can obtain this id and act upon it.
Any ideas or tips please ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently logged in user, you need to use the following API:
https://backendless.com/documentation/users/android/users_get_current_user.htm

If there is no logged in user, the method will return null.